# Browser.msgBox with CANCEL

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

We have this code below is working fine, except but when you hit cancel, the script still run (  email() and copy(), in stead of cancel Do you see what is my wrong ?

Thank

```
function combine()
```

{
var confirm_yc = Browser.msgBox('AreYouSure', 'Confirm ?', Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL);

```
  if (confirm_yc == 'ok')
    SendEmail();
  copy();
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At your following script,

```
function combine() {
  var confirm_yc = Browser.msgBox('AreYouSure', 'Confirm ?', Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL);
  if (confirm_yc == 'ok')
    SendEmail();
  copy();
}
```

The if statement of `if (confirm_yc == 'ok')` doesn't use `{}`. In this case, when `confirm_yc == 'ok'` is `true`, `SendEmail()` and `copy()` are run. On the other hand, when `confirm_yc == 'ok'` is `false`, `SendEmail()` is not run. But `copy()` is run. I thought that this might be the reason of your issue. So in your script, how about the following modification?

```
function combine() {
  var confirm_yc = Browser.msgBox('AreYouSure', 'Confirm ?', Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL);
  if (confirm_yc == 'ok') {
    SendEmail();
    copy();
  }
}
```

#### Reference:

- [if...else](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else)

Comment: @Tu PHAN Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.